# How to get data using cURL through Proxy connection

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I would like to open any url with help of cURL using proxy connection. Below are the codes... still we are not able to connect this and getting positive data through this function Please provide the suitable help to resolve this issue. Every time i run this code. I got the "Else" conditioned message.

```
<?php
function getPage($proxy, $url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    $result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
    $result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
?>
<?php
$result = getPage(
    '[64.71.138.122]:[80]', // use valid proxy
    'http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter',
    'http://www.google.com/',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
    1,
    5);

if (empty($result['ERR'])) {
    echo "Positive message" ;
} else {
    echo "Negative Message" ;
}
?>
```

When we print this "print_r($result);" the result would be ..........

```
        Array ( [EXE] => [INF] => Array ( [url] => http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 5.019769 [namelookup_time] => 0.000129 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 ) [ERR] => connect() timed out! )
```

Comment: If you `echo $result['ERR'];`, what does it say?

Comment: also, I'm pretty sure `[64.71.138.122]:[80]` should just say `64.71.138.122` (although I could be wrong about this)

Comment: Please can you test by just supplying the IP address to the `$proxy` argument. Also please verfiy with a browser that the proxy actually works, and that it will accept requests from your server.

Comment: How can i check it on our server.

Comment: If you check it from your PC it would be a good start (i.e. make sure it works at all) - To verify that it will accept requests from your server you could contact the owner of the proxy and make sure they do not have a blacklist/whitelist in operation. A simple test would be to see if `$fp = fsockopen('64.71.138.122',80,$errCode,$errStr,5); echo $errStr;` succeeds

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html#authenticating
You should really understand what you have copied  http://www.fromzerotoseo.com/scraping-websites-php-curl-proxy/

you can use

```
function curl_google($keyword){

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q='.urlencode($keyword).'&btnG=Google+Search&meta=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
return $data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

}
```

but you have do parse the results (maybe using SimpleXMLElement)...good luck

Comment: Is it possible to use this script for bulk use ?

Comment: more explicit please, you can use SOAP also, although the google api doesn`t work...i tryed today...